# What's the UIFont text style of this big title?

Tags: ios, uifont, dynamic-type-feature

I would like my app to support dynamic font sizes and I'm wondering what's the `UIFont` `textstyle` of this big "Welcome to Videos" title here:

[image]

This is what I'm currently using but it's way too small:

```
titleLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
```

`title1` isn't working either. What is Apple using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`headline` *used* to be the largest `UIFont.TextStyle` (ex. [older guides](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/supporting-dynamic-type/)).

Now, `largeTitle` is the largest and better matches your screenshot:

`label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle)`

To match even further, you'll want a version of that font with the bold trait. With [this extension], you can do:

`label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle).bold()`

Which results in:

[image]

Also see https://www.iosfontsizes.com/:

```
.largeTitle     34.0    SFUIDisplay
.title1         28.0    SFUIDisplay (-Light ≤ iOS 10)
.title2         22.0    SFUIDisplay
.title3         20.0    SFUIDisplay
.headline       17.0    SFUIText-Semibold
.subheadline    15.0    SFUIText
.body           17.0    SFUIText
.callout        16.0    SFUIText
.footnote       13.0    SFUIText
.caption1       12.0    SFUIText
.caption2       11.0    SFUIText
```

Comment: `UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle).bold()` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can go [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/) and get all the sizes (with weights) for each enum value.
You can also change the dynamic type size and see the difference.

[image: Font size weight and leading for each dynamic font type]

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to `Arial boldMT`. You can compare it in this table. [enter link description here](http://iosfonts.com)

Comment: I believe it is the standard San Francisco font. What makes you think it's Arial?

Comment: Yes, this may be San Francisco, but it is also very similar to Arial

Answer (score 0):

**For Title**

System font - Bold style

**SubTitle**

System font - Medium style

**Body**

System font - Light style

Comment: So which style is it? None of them match I think.

Comment: That's not a style that's a font name

Comment: You can use Bold style, Medium style and light style